# YII2 gridview dont display the correct data

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have few tables. position(to holds all positions), applicants(to hold all applicants) and assign_applicant(to say which position is held by what applicant - many to many reln).

So data is like for assign_applicant table

```
pos  applicant
2      1
2      3
3      4
3      5
```

I want to display the records like this. but instead it shows :

```
pos  applicant
2    1,3 (array)
3    4,5 (array)
```

The reason is (many) relations:

```
 public function getAssign()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\admin\models\AssignApplicant::className(), ["job_position_id" => "id"]);
    }

    public function getApplicant()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(\admin\models\Applicant::className(), ["id" => "applicant_id"]) ->via('assign');
    }
```

Here is the grid view:

```
 <?=
    GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'layout' => "{pager}\n{summary}\n{items}\n{pager}",
        'filterPosition' => \yii\grid\GridView::FILTER_POS_HEADER,
        'responsive' => true,
        'hover' => true,
        'resizableColumns' => true,
        'floatHeader' => true,
        'autoXlFormat' => true,
        'export' => [
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            'showConfirmAlert' => true,
            'target' => GridView::TARGET_BLANK
        ],
        'panel' => [
            'type' => 'primary',
            'heading' => ''
        ],
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
            [
                'attribute' => 'position',
                'format' => 'raw',
                'value' => function ($model)
                {
                    return Html::a($model->positionName, yii\helpers\Url::toRoute(['position/update', 'id' => $model->position_id]));
                }
                    ],
                    [
                        'attribute' => 'applicantName',
                        'value' => 'applicantName'
                    ],

                ],
            ]);
            ?>
```

My query (raw form):

```
SELECT  `job_positions` . * , applicant.first_name, assign_applicant.id
FROM  `job_positions` 
LEFT JOIN  `position` ON  `job_positions`.`position_id` =  `position`.`id` 
INNER JOIN  `assign_applicant` ON  `job_positions`.`id` =  `assign_applicant`.`job_position_id` 
INNER JOIN  `applicant` ON  `assign_applicant`.`applicant_id` =  `applicant`.`id` 
WHERE (
`client_id` =  '1'
)
AND (
`shift_id` =  '1'
)
AND (
`date` =  '2016-12-08'
)
ORDER BY  `position`.`name` 
LIMIT 20
```

Any way to show the data like I want

Comment: Add the code for your GridView. Also do you have a model representing the `assign_applicant` table?

Comment: @topher - added code

Comment: Instead of showing positions with related applicants show applicants with related positions.

Comment: @Bizley 2  I didn't get your point.

Comment: You are obviously listing all positions showing related applicants. Because there are many applicants for one position you got array of them. Instead list all applicants - every applicant is connected to the one position he's applying to - so the list will look like you want.

Comment: @Ish Can an applicant have more than one position?

Comment: @Bizley 2 That is not possible. I have added my query. Looking at them getting applicant from position is the better way.

Comment: @topher - No, only 1 position per applicant.

Comment: Maybe change INNER JOIN to LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Bizley - tired. doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

yii2 intentionally [removes duplicated models](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/db/ActiveQuery.php#L238) when processing results.

your can either use `applicants` (or `assign_applicant`) as primary model as @Bizley suggested 
or process the resulting models beforehand (using clone and [populateRelation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord.html#populateRelation()-detail) to obtain the desired structure)